# Allow Launching multiple instances of an App Bundle in macOS

Tags: macos, app-bundle

I have a couple of bash scripts wrapped as apps, like transcoding videos with ffmpeg or uploading files to FTP right from the Finder. Before Big Sur, it was possible to open the app multiple times to process files in parallel. It was nice but it’s gone since Big Sur. I tried the key `LSMultipleInstancesProhibited` in my `Info.plist` but it doesn’t help. One workaround I came up with, would be to call the main script from the executable and sending it to the background with `&`. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed to get it working. Every time that the application is launched this is what happens:

1. The `fork()` function duplicate the process

   **NOTE**: If you are using Swift code you need to set the Objective-C bridging header and write in the respective `.c` file something like this:

   ```
   int myFork() {

       return fork();
   }
   ```
2. The parent process just call `exit(0)`
3. The child process keeps running the app or call `execv` to start another app / executable or the same app itself 
   **NOTE**: You can't use NSApplication and related objects on child process if you use `fork` but if you call `execv` with the main app executable the all NSApplication is reinitialized and it works flawlessly. Of course the app will be restarted and you have to use some parameter to detect if it's the original child or the `execv` one
4. Since the parent died the system records the app as "*not running*"
5. If the app icon is clicked again then another instance will be launched even if the previous one is still runniing